# Can a subsite inherit Result Types?

Tags: 2013

I added a result type to my root site collection. However when I add a Content Search Results web part to a page in my subsite it doesn't use the result type. I have to add the result type again to the subsite. This seems like unnecessary duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are creating Result type in the site collection level.

If you want to create a result type for a site collection:

1. Ensure that you are an administrator for the site collection.
2. In the site collection, go to Settings > Site settings, and then in the Site Collection Administration section, click Search Result Types.

Comment: I've added it to the site collection level. On the Manage Result Types page I can see my custom result type under the heading 'Defined for this site'.